# How to set different useState when it's mobile and desktop mode in REACT?

Tags: reactjs, responsive, use-effect

I want to have 12 products when it's desktop mode, 8 products when it's mobile.
I tried to use useEffect to re-render when mobileScreen is used. But it doesn't work at all.
I've been struggling for several hours with this. Please help me :(

```
const [productsPerPage, setProductsPerPage] = useState(12);
const mobileScreen = useMediaQuery({ query: 'max-width: 600px' })

useEffect(()=>{
    if (mobileScreen){
        return setPostsPerPage(8)
    }
}, [mobileScreen])
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the code:

```
const [productsPerPage, setProductsPerPage] = useState(12);
// check the syntax of query
const mobileScreen = useMediaQuery({ query: `(max-width: 600px)` })

useEffect(()=>{
    if (mobileScreen){
    // you don't need return statement here.
      setPostsPerPage(8)
    }
}, [mobileScreen])
```